# Ruby regex replaces between quotes and not contents

Tags: ruby, regex

I want the following spaces within the quotes to be stripped out, but only the spaces that are contiguous before and after a quote within matching quotes.

`this is " a " quoted "string " with "  lots" of "edge " cases " that " need spaces removed. It \" also \" has "escaped" quotes just to really annoy you!`

It should look like...

`this is "a" quoted "string" with "lots" of "edge" cases "that" need spaces removed. It \"also\" has "escaped" quotes just to really annoy you!`

I's this even possible in a single regex?  If not then any solution will do.

Comment: [*Simple*](http://regex101.com/r/qY1rZ2)

Comment: @HamZa why don't you formulate this as an answer so Marc can accept it? It seems to be a perfect solution.

Comment: @p11y Voted to close it as he didn't try anything. I don't want to earn points that way

Comment: @HamZa well sometimes you just don't know how to get started on a problem and this might just be one of those cases I guess (looking at some of his other questions). But I must say you are acting in a very honorable way ;-)

Comment: @p11y you just gave me a brilliant idea "community wiki"

Comment: I tried many approaches, the main problem is I suck at regex so instead of hacking getting know-where I thought to let the smarter folks with more regex experience give it a shot

Comment: I'll try that site @HamZa, never seen that one before!  Thanks much!

Comment: @Marc there is one for ruby it's called [rubular](http://rubular.com), for some reason I don't know how to replace there. Maybe because I'm not a ruby dev :) ?

Comment: It's not often I ask questions on Stack Overflow, but when I do, I truly have no clue whats going on!  Stay thirsty my friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a pretty annoying one, heh

```
str = %Q{this is " a " quoted "string " with " lots" of "edge " cases " that " need spaces removed. It \\" also \\" has "escaped" quotes just to really annoy you!}

str.gsub! /(\\?"|)((?:.(?!\1))+.)(?:\1)/ do |match|
  match.gsub(/^(\\?")\s+|\s+(\\?")$/, "\\1\\2").strip
end
```

Nevertheless...

```
this is "a" quoted "string" with "lots" of "edge" cases "that" need spaces removed. It \"also\" has "escaped" quotes just to really annoy you!
```

---

**Regexp Visualization**

[image: regexp]

---

The reason this is so annoying is because `str.gsub!` yields a string to the block instead of `MatchData` like `str.match` would.  Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something by I feel this is a bit easier:

```
str.gsub(/("|\\").*?\1/){|x| x.delete(' ')}
```

I will however remove all spaces in between quotes. This is more correct but a bit ugly:

```
str.gsub(/("|\\")(.*?)("|\\")/){$1+$2.strip+$3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.gsub /(\\?")\s*([^"\s]+)\s*(\\?")/, '\1\2\3'
```